# Chrome Extension message listener not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from my chrome extension popup window to the content script of the page, but the listener is not picking up the sent messages.

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ greeting: "hello" })
```

**main.js (content script, part of the DOM)**

The Listener is not picking up the sent messages:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
  console.log("message received")
  if (request.greeting == "hello") {
    console.log("hello message")
  }
})
```

**manifest.json**

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Go Go Ninja Computers",
    "version": "0.54",
    "description": "This extension is trying to send a message.",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ],
    "content_scripts": 
    [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["main.js"],
            "css" : ["style.css"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Ninja Pirate",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

I am just following [these basic instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple), so I'm quite baffled why this isn't working? I'm also not sure if 'background.js' needs to be included, but without it, I cannot use console.log in popup.js.

Comment: To send to a content script you need chrome.**tabs**.sendMessage and specify the tab id in the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now that you mention it...